# manipulating leading constraints programmatically Swift 4

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, swift4

how to find leading constraints of UIView programmatically in Swift 4 and how to manipulate leading constraints programmatically?

Comment: Did you create those constraints? What is the setup? What is the context of the problem?

Comment: I m creating those constraints  and dynamically changing  frame using pan gesture.

Comment: If you have created a constraint programmatically, just store its reference to a property, and you can access it anytime. If it is a storyboard-created constraint, link it to a `@IBOutlet` property, and again, you'll be able to access it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
 for con in otherView.constraints {
   if(con.firstAttribure == NSLayoutAttribute.leading) {
       /// here con is a leading constraint
    }
 }
```

or better use constraint Identifier to quickly find it